# Error when trying to change the value of a cell with a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, edit

Since May 1st several of my scripts show me an error message when trying to change the value of a cell. I have a main user and a second user with permissions to modify those ranges. with the main user there is no problem, but with the second user the error is shown

```
 var saldoreal =     ss2.getSheetByName("Resumen").getRange("C23").getValue();
                     ss2.getSheetByName("Resumen").getRange("G15").setValue(saldoreal);
   
 var saldoestimado = ss2.getSheetByName("Resumen").getRange("C30").getValue();  
                     ss2.getSheetByName("Resumen").getRange("C27").setValue(saldoestimado);
```

In this case saldoreal could be procesed and after that i get the error and stop the script
CEll C27 has permissions to be edited

Any idea?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 1):

if the main user is working well, try to look at the edit permission, or protected range.

Besides, here an idea to reduce function call :

```
var sheet = ss2.getSheetByName("Resumen");

var saldoreal = sheet.getRange("C23").getValue();
sheet.getRange("G15").setValue(saldoreal);
   
var saldoestimado = sheet.getRange("C30").getValue();  
sheet.getRange("C27").setValue(saldoestimado);
```